# how use return variable value in other page

Tags: php, function, pdo, return

Hi i'm trying to use OOP concept in Select query pdo. I want load database values in Select tag in HTML. Following is Selection Tag coding.

```
<?php includer='function.php'; ?>
<select class="form-control" id="old_category" name="old_category">
                                    <option value="0"  >---</option>
                                    <?php 
                                    $sql= new items();
                                    $sql->show_register_items_category();
                                    foreach($sql as $row){
                                    ?>
<option><?php echo $sql;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

And in function.php file i have created following code.

```
<?php
include_once '../db/connection.php';
$con=new connection();
$dbg=$con->db;



class items
{
    public function show_registered_items_category()
    {
        $sql="SELECT `category` FROM `available_items` GROUP BY `category` ORDER BY `category` ASC";
        this.$stmt=$dbg->query($sql);
        $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //return $stmt;
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

Please can someone tell me how can i use this return variable $rows in other file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php includer='function.php'; ?>
<select class="form-control" id="old_category" name="old_category">
     <option value="0"  >---</option>
     <?php 
     $sql= new items();
     //this is how you use this return variable $rows in other file.
     $rows=$sql->show_register_items_category();
     //haven't checked the foreach
     foreach($rows as $row){
     ?>
     <option><?php echo $row;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```